# Ignore repeated days values using MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, saiku

How can i ignore repeated days values using MDX ?

For example, from this:

- 12/1/1997
- 12/2/1997
- 12/3/1998
- 12/4/1999

To this:

- 12

I'm already tried use Distinct, but i'ts like they still considere as unique dates.

```
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS,
  DISTINCT([Time].[Weekly].[Day].Members) ON ROWS FROM [Sales 2]
```

Comment: Your model should support this. You should add a new member to your Time dimension with that value. [Month] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

These are different values and your cube treats them as such. I guess you can do some mimicing of that behavior with MDX by creating a MEMBER which has just the date part and doing distinct on that member. Something like:

```
WITH MEMBER [MonthPart] AS LEFT([Time].[Weekly].[Day].currentMember, 2) 

SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS,
  DISTINCT([MonthPart].Members) ON ROWS FROM [Sales 2]
```

Something like that but I am not sure for the correct syntax.

The proper way to fix that though is to create a good Time Dimension for your dates in the cube. There you can define hierarchies, levels and just take the [Month] part which will give you what you want (and will be much faster than writing complex MDX queries)